# grails domain class expose id for java classes

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a fairly simple question about grails domain classes.  I am not sure I know how to phrase it correctly since I can't seem to find the answer on google.

I have a groovy domain class

```
class DomainObject {
    String name
    String email
}
```

and a java class that uses this domain object.

```
public class DomainUser {
    public void method() {
        DomainObject object = new DomainObject();
        object.getId();
    }
}
```

however I get an error on the line

`object.getId();`

with the **message:**

The method `getId()` is undefined for the type

How do I expose the id to the java class since it is auto generated by the grails application/hibernate?

Comment: What is giving you the error?  `grails compile` or your IDE?  There's lots of semi-magical stuff added to Grails artefact classes by AST transformations at compile time (one of which is `getId()` for domain classes), and if your IDE is not aware of these transformations it'll fail.

Comment: Also, a side comment, Grails overrides domain class constructors through the metaclass mechanism to make things like autowiring of services into domains work correctly.  So if you want to "new" a domain class in Java code you should use `InvokerHelper.invokeNoArgumentsConstructorOf(DomainClass.class)` which is the Java way to call the metaclass-provided constructor rather than the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id field is generated at run-time and java does not know any thing about dynamic references.
Access that domain from service layer. 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#usingServicesFromJava

also google: "grails access service java"

first result is http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Question-How-do-I-reference-a-Grails-service-from-within-Java-class-td1462056.html

You can write some thing like this in your DomainService.groovy

```
class DomainService(){
    def persistAndGetNewDomain(){
       new Domain().save(flush:true)    
    }
}
```

Also you must add the id field to your domain class

```
class DomainObject {
    Long id
    String name
    String email
}
```